# excel range seems to keep information about the reason why it has been created

Tags: excel, vba

Take a look at the example: i've created a 'regular' range and from it 
two ranges: one by calling "columns" property and the other by calling "rows" property. 
Now, while they seem to be regular ranges as well, and while they refer to the same worksheet area, the default method behaves differently.

```
Public Sub RangeTest01()

Dim r As Range

' i get a 'regular' range on the active sheet of 3 columns and 3 rows
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C3")

Dim rr As Range
Set rr = r.Rows
Debug.Print "rr: range generated by the call 'Rows' on the original range"
Debug.Print "1. what kind of object is it? " & TypeName(rr)
Debug.Print "2. what are the sheet cell it refers to? " & rr.Address
Debug.Print "3. what does the default method call produce?" & rr(1).Address

Dim rc As Range
Set rc = r.Columns
Debug.Print "rc: range generated by the call 'Columns' on the original range"
Debug.Print "1. what kind of object is it? " & TypeName(rc)
Debug.Print "2. what are the sheet cell it refers to? " & rc.Address
Debug.Print "3. what does the default method call produce?" & rc(1).Address
End Sub
```

#### Output

```
rr: range generated by the call 'Rows' on the original range

1. what kind of object is it? Range
2. what are the sheet cell it refers to? $A$1:$C$3
3. what does the default method call produce?$A$1:$C$1

rc: range generated by the call 'Columns' on the original range

1. what kind of object is it? Range
2. what are the sheet cell it refers to? $A$1:$C$3
3. what does the default method call produce?$A$1:$A$3
```

#### Questions

So not all the ranges on the same data 'are created equal', the best description I can find about the behavior I see here is that "a range keeps the piece of information about the reason why it has been created", and behaves differently on the basis of this information.

So if it has been created for working with columns it keeps a sort of 'column-based' flag, and the opposite way round if it has been created for working with rows.

Questions are: 
Is it accessible this piece of information? Are out there other 'changing' types of Ranges or other objects that should be looked where they originated to know how they behave?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an object containing a series of ranges split by either column objects or row objects, they behave differently because you've defined them with different methods.

If you did `rcells = r.cells` and run the same process I'm sure it would output 
$A$1:$A$1 on point 3. Or maybe just $A$1 - Would be interesting to see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to tell differently created ranges apart from one another for sure, but on the other hand I don't think it is necessary either.

Since a range object is a collection-like object containing an (ordered) set of other ranges, it can be iterated and addressed by an index.
Lets have a look at the following range properties that return another range object themselves, based on the range they were applied to:

- `Rows` - contains all cells of the current range divided in single rows
- `Columns` - contains all cells of the current range divided in single columns
- `Cells` - contains all cells of the current range, divided in single cells, one after another (if you iterate it you get cells of the first row, column by column, then the same for the second row and so forth)
- `EntireRow` - contains all cells in the worksheet divided by rows, but only those rows that the current range covers: think of the current range being extended to all columns
- `EntireColumn` - contains all cells in the worksheet divided by columns, but only those columns that the current range covers: think of the current range being extended to all rows

So, depending on the property, the return value will have the cells differently 'sliced' into parts that can then be iterated or addressed by an index. But all properties still return the same cells, just ordered differently (except for the Entire* properties that also return all other cells in their respective row/column).

Now, if you have to handle a range object but have no knowledge of how the range was created, just apply any of the above properties to it to have it return the cells in the way you like.
Since all of those range properties return ranges themselves, you can apply them multiple times.
For example, consider changing your code like this:

```
Set rr = r.Rows.Columns
...
Set rc = r.Columns.Rows
```

The output will be identical, just switched between the two blocks. What were lists of rows before became lists of columns and vice versa.

Comment: @AgostinoX: Does this answer your question? Is something missing? Please let me know if I can enhance this answer so you'll find it acceptable.